# Is it possible returning arrays from functions in php for-loop

Tags: php, arrays, function

The 1st for-loop is to retrieve `$projSDE_1` which is employee ID and it's a value that changes every loop round.

```
$projSDE_1_IDs = [];
for($i=0; $i<db_rowcount();$i++)//1st for
{
$projSDE_1=db_get($i,8);
array_push($projSDE_1_IDs,$projSDE_1);
}
$projSDE_1_names = func_GetEmpNameNew($projSDE_1_IDs,$projSDE_1);
```

Next,the 2nd for-loop is going to retrieve all data and display it.All i need is each row will be able to display `$projSDE_1_names` by `func_GetEmpNameNew($projSDE_1_IDs,$projSDE_1);`

```
for($j=0; $j<db_rowcount();$j++)//2nd for
{
<tr >
<tbody>
<td style='width:5%'>".$no.".&nbsp;</a></td>
<td>".$projID."&nbsp;</td>
<td>".$projClient."&nbsp;</td>";
<td>".$projSDE_1_names."&nbsp;</td>";
</tbody>
</tr>
}//endfor
```

function to get `$projSDE_1_names`

```
function func_GetEmpNameNew($empIDs) {

$names = [];
 foreach($empIDs as $empID){

  $sqlEmp="select EmpID,LastName2_c from empbasic WHERE EmpID= '".$empID."'";

    db_select($sqlEmp);

    $rowcount=db_rowcount();

    if(db_rowcount()>0){

        for($f=0;$f<count($empIDs);$f++){
            $empID=db_get($f,0);
            $empName=db_get($f,1);
            array_push($names, $empName);

        }//for
    }//if

       }//foreach

return $names;

 } // function

 var_dump($projSDE_1_names); // Display the array to see if you get all the correct data.
```

The function is work fine and its able returns an array with the employees names..[`var_dump($projSDE_1_names);`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzpFG.png)
So far this is the result i get - [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmp6z.png).

The list of name that displayed at the top is by

```
   foreach ($projSDE_1_names as $projSDE_1_name) {
   echo $projSDE_1_name.'-';
    }
```

I need each name for each row.It listed 10 names from function and its suppose for 10 rows.All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fix the wrong issue.

Judging from your code, the initial list of values is retrieved from a relational database. The subsequent results are also retrieved from a relational database.

This alone is very wrong (unless the we are talking about 2 separate instances of DBMS which are unable to communicate directly). The right way to retrieve the 2 sets of data is using a JOIN on the data.

But that isn't the only howler in your code.

Repeatedly generating and executing a select statement in a loop is very bad practice. This would be solved by the same approach as the first issue above. However in the event of cases where the reference dataset does not originate on the same relational DBMS there are better ways to solve the problem. I would make a suggestion, but the db_ functions in your code are not standard PHP functions. The behaviour exposed in your code seems like a very cumbersome and limiting interface. Using mysqli you could simply....

```
function func_GetEmpNameNew($empIDs) {
  global $db_handle;
  $sqlEmp="select EmpID,LastName2_c from empbasic WHERE EmpID IN ("
       . implode(",", $empID) // assuming the inputs are trusted and integer values
       ")";
  $res=mysqli_query($db_handle, $sqlEmp);
  return mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

As a side note you are using the order in which the data is returned in the orinal query as a means of indexing the result sets. As long as you are retrieving a single row each time, the data will matchup - but your code might retrieve zero, one or more than one row each time - again the solution is to run one query with a join. If you need to run queries against aseperate datasources, then index the array by a primary key attribute from the original dataset.